# Convert very large non-UTF-8 Blob to ASCII String?

Tags: apex

I want to convert the Blob into readable String. My custom file format contains a some header information which I would like to read it. So I was using the following code

```
public static String blobToString(Blob input, String inCharset){

    String hex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(input);
    System.assertEquals(0, hex.length() & 1);
    final Integer bytesCount = hex.length() >> 1;
    String[] bytes = new String[bytesCount];
    for(Integer i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i)
        bytes[i] =  hex.mid(i << 1, 2);
    return EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%' + String.join(bytes, '%'), inCharset);
}
```

Which I got from Salesforce StackExchange only.

But the code works with small amount of data (Less than a KB), its taking too much time on large amount of data. Actually the author of this code warned about that , but I didn't had any other option left as I am a newbie with Apex.

So I expect somebody here can help me out in resolving this issue.

Thanking you all

Syam

Comment: I assume the question/answer you are referencing is ['BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string' error?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25421/102)

Comment: Have you tried [Blob.toString()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_blob.htm#apex_System_Blob_toString)?

Comment: Yes I did tried as its not a valid UTF-8 string it will throw the error.