# Comparing a text with a attachment body

Tags: apex, trigger, attachment

I want to compare a text with a attachment that is added to a custom object. For example, check if the word "Test" is placed in the attachment body.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to convert the `Body` data (`Blob` Type) to text (`String` type).

```
Attachment record; // defined in your context somewhere
Blob body = record.Body; // Blob data type
String content = body.toString(); // converted to text
system.debug(content.contains('Test')); // string manipulation as needed
```

Comment: Hi Adrian,Thanks for your response but when I run this code getting an error that says "Blob is not a valid UTF-8 string", below is the code which I checked, attachment tpye might be a word or a PDF,                                                                                "Attachment record=   [Select Id,ParentId, Name,body,ContentType From Attachment where ParentId='a0328000008srNO'];
Blob body = record.Body; // Blob data type
String content = body.toString(); // converted to text
system.debug(content.contains('Test')); // string manipulation as needed

Comment: Where are you getting the files from? You can't really work around the error in Apex. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11805/blob-is-not-a-valid-utf-8-string-error